# How to compare object key as array value and assign a value to the variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

I have an object that contains multiple ids in an array:

```
"Headers" [
  {
    ...
    "listOfIds": [236, 242, 250, 289],
    ...
  }
]
```

In my react component how can I use this array to compare if the ids in my redux store matches with any of the ones in the array. If it contains any of those ids, then I need to apply the class name to the variable.

My current code:

```
const reduxState = useSelector(state=> state);

_.map(Headers, (item, index) => {
  const { listOfIds } = item;
  let className = '';
  if(_.get(reduxState, 'common.id', null) != listOfIds) {
    className = 'hidden'
  }
})
```

Comment: Your question title and question body differ considerably. All you appear to be trying to do is searching an array to see if a property's value matches any of its members... Or to put it another way, if the array [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) your property value.

Comment: It is, of course, unclear what `Headers` is, or why you're using `_.map` without using the resulting array, or what you're going to do with `className`, since it loses scope once the map's iteration has completed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i dont use react but maybe you could use the "includes()" function of array types.

For example:

```
let array = [236, 242, 250, 289];
let find = 250;
if (array.includes(find)) { 
// your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
const hasCommonId = Headers.some(({listOfIds}) => listOfIds.includes(reduxState?.common.id));

let className;
if (hasCommonId) {
  className = 'hidden'; // this should probably be a call to setState
}
```